# find the hidden field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with an image on each row with a hover event attached. Can someone please show me how to alert the value of the hidden field?

```
<div class='first'>
    <input type="hidden" value="target">
    <div class='second'>
        <img src="yada" />
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, you could do :

```
$("img[src='yada']").parent().prev().attr('value');
```

To get the value.

But, it's not a good practice. This code will easily break when you change your HTML structure.

Comment: You could use 
    .prev("input[type='hidden']") 
instead of 
    parent().prev()

Answer (score 2):

Give the hidden field an id:

```
<input id="hidden_yada" type="hidden" value="target">
```

And get the value directly:

```
$("#hidden_yada").attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the image tag object in your event handler, then get the parentNode and traverse the DOM tree to get the value.